# Navigation controller inside a container

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a scenario where I need to **add a navigationController inside a container** (the intension is to make a sideMenu which will slide in from side of the screen). I have successfully added the navigation bar inside the view and when I click on a button the page is navigating to another view, all this happen inside a container view. Everything was fine but when I use popViewController from the inside view the container itself is gone and I cant get the sideMenu anymore. ***When I click the back button from the rightmostView the sideMenu(which is added inside the leftmostView) is gone foreever.*** If anyone had same issues while using NavigationController, how was it resolved? Refer the image I have shared to understand the scenario:

[image]

Comment: you rightMostVC is presented or show(pushed) on stack?

Comment: it is pushed from the didselectrow of 3rd vc(with two green buttons). @ibnetariq

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the autolayout constraint. Solved thanks to [@ibnetariq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768713/navigation-controller-inside-a-container/48821046#comment84538155_48768713).